# CocoaPods/Specs cloning from github takes too much time

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, git, cocoapods

I tried many time to clone this url

> git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git

But it shows like the following, how to fix this issue? Please help me.

```
$ /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master --progress
  Cloning into 'master'...
  remote: Counting objects: 1082703, done.        
  remote: Compressing objects: 100% (279/279), done.        
  Receiving objects:   2% (25216/1082703), 5.03 MiB | 16.00 KiB/s
```

Sometime it may breaking like after 50% completed and also showing following error

```
error: RPC failed; curl 56 SSLRead() return error -9806 MiB/s   
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Comment: its about to 500+ MB's so yah that will be take time :)

Comment: Sorry, I usually don't like "counter-questions", but WHY do you want to clone the specs repo? You realize this is basically just a giant repository of all specs there are, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the most recent version, try

```
git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git
```

It will decrease the size to 1/3.

Also, depending on your network condition, a proxy might help.